# Hibernate - Forcing @OneToMany to be EAGER via join and NOT multiple select statements

Tags: hibernate

```
@Entity
public class User{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;


    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Role.class,cascade= CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

   //getters and setters are here
}
```

I would like to fetch the `User` object with its `roles`, the problem is that hibernate is actually running 2 different queries to do this. one of the `User` and the other for `roles`.

im using

```
crudRepository.findById();
```

How can I force Hibernate to fetch this object in one single query via join?

**SMAL CLARIFICATION**
`Role` class also has `@OnToMany` but I don't care to run this query once someone logs in to the system. its small amount of data. 
Thanks

Comment: You can refer [Using Hibernate to Join to Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359049/using-hibernate-to-join-to-tables) this answer

Comment: @AhmadQureshi this is what Im doing. `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`

Answer (score 0):

You can try Hibernate.initialize() 
Ex :  `User u = crudRepository.findById();
Hibernte.initialize(u.getRoles());`

Comment: Thanks, isn't `Hibernte.initialize` comes after the query was running?